# Van Toll's <cross> strike-out fails

Tags: html, css

I don't get the expected decisive X across my struck-out text.

Here's my test code. Everything within the 'style' is copied directly from VanToll, but it doesn't cross stuff out. Clearly there are things about ::css  words that I don't understand. What have I left out?

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>
<title>X-out test</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
/* Emphatic X-shaped strike-out */
/* https://www.tjvantoll.com/2013/09/12/building-custom- 
text-strikethroughs-with-css/ */

.cross {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}
.cross::before, .cross::after {
content: '';
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 50%;
}
.cross::before {
border-bottom: 2px solid red;
-webkit-transform: skewY(-10deg);
transform: skewY(-10deg);
}
.cross::after {
border-bottom: 2px solid red;
-webkit-transform: skewY(10deg);
transform: skewY(10deg);
}
</style> </head> <body>

<h3><cross>This section-header should be struck out!</cross> 
</h3>

</body> </html>
```

VanToll recommended "if you include a live jsFiddle and/or jsBin of your attempt to get this to work it’ll help a lot as well" but I haven't a clue what these js... operations are. (I'm an author writing an academic book in HTML rather than a real programmer.)

The old standby 's' works where 'cross' appears above, but half the time it appears as a 1-pixel line just above the lower serifs of the text, where it might be seen as a confused underline.

For the record, I'm writing in BBEdit under High Sierra 10.13.6 on a 2013 27"-iMac, with Firefox my usual browser, although half-dozen others work too. See 
http://electromontis.net/evoligion/_D/D15.shtml#17
for an example of the poorly placed  strikeout.

Answer (score 2):

Try adjusting your code as follows:

```
<h3 class="cross">This section-header should be struck out!</h3>
```

Note the addition of `class="cross"`, and the removal of the `<cross>` and `</cross>`

Answer (score 0):

Your css code like a div tag but your html code doesn't match.

Try this

```
<div class="cross">This section-header should be struck out!</div>
```

Comment: No effect so far.

Answer (score 0):

The fix above/below worked well for 3 years after I got it sorted out.  (I am, incidentally, now using macOS Catalina 10.15.7 and BBEdit 13.5.6.)   I used the strikeout code to emphasize certain sections in the Table of Contents of a chapter in an HTML book that described non-existent features (the html link in the original query no longer works).  The ToC is an unordered list, in a 3-column 'newspaper'  format, and one day the 6 crossed out entries were simply blank. I hadn't looked at that chapter for a while, so I have no idea what or when it happened.

The best that I can do now is to get one such strikeout to cross out the first entry in the ToC.

The newspaper code:

```
.newsp {
padding-left; 1.5mm;
column-gap;  2mm;
column-count: 3;
column-width: 33%;
line-height: 2.3;
font-size: 10pt;
font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
list-style-type: none;
border: black solid 1px:
}
```

The cross-out code:

```
.x   {
position: relative;
display; inline-block;
}
.x::after   {
content:"";
width: 14%;
position: absolute;
left: 1.05in;
top: 53%;
border-top: 2px solid red;
-webkit-transform: skewY(-4deg);
moz-webkit-transform: skewY(-4deg);
ms-webkit-transform: skewY(-4deg);
o-webkit-transform: skewY(-4deg);
transform: skewY(-4deg);
}
```

and this  all comes together in the middle of the ToC:

```
<li><a href-"#y27"><span class="x">Section 11</span></a>
<li><a href-"#y28"><span class="x">Section 12</span></a>
<li><a href-"#y29"><span class="x">Section 13</span></a>
```

but all it accomplishes is to leave blanks lines in the list.

Further to the mystification is that the name  "x"  used to work just fine. Now I get a single line, with the correct angle, length and color, and I can persuade it to cross out the first entry in the first column of the list -- **without specifically mentioning "x" in the HTML code** (after I have removed all my calls to "x").  If I rename it, say, "xx", all I get is blanks.  A painstaking search for a typewritten "x" anywhere in the HTML code turns up nothing.  When it is named "x"  I can adjust the details of its angle, color, etc. but I can't move it to its proper position in the newspaper table.  I know for a fact that Powweb, my web service, rewrites my HTML code, although they don't seem to want to talk about this, but I need reassurance that I have not missed something new about CSS and HTML. Or done something utterly stupid that I can't see.

--Ferren  20210622 at 00:00:15